# (How) Can I disconnect internal secondary hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a windows on 500GB SSD and other data on 1TB HDD. The HDD is very loud (It annoys me only because it's on the right side and the assimetry gets is very noticable).

I have found an option for that in windows but even if I set it to turn off after 1 min of idleness, it keeps running.

I want the hdd to be turned off when I don't want to use it.

Is there an option to disconnect it? Like, on an external drive I unplug it. Can I virtually unplug it?

Comment: Delete it from Device Manager, then unplug power cord. When you need in it plug power cord back - OS will find and attach it.

Comment: Use the Disable function for the drive in device manager.

Comment: @Moab HDD will not stop and will continue to make noise.

Comment: I understand it is an internal disk. What was the option you found in Windows?

Comment: Unplugging us not very convenient, since it is a laptop.

Comment: Im not sure which one is the hdd in the device manager.

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21454-turn-off-hard-disk-after-idle-windows-10-a.html
This page shows the setting I had found